# Preventing a method from being called/overridden in another bundle

Tags: java, osgi

I have this abstract class `myapi.MyAbstract` which is extended by client bundles.

```
package myclientbundle;

import myapi.MyAbstract;

public class MyClass extends MyAbstract {
    // Implementation
}
```

I need to add a non-API method at `myapi.MyAbstract`, but I can't find a way of doing that. That method is intended to be called only from inside my API bundle.

The closest I've got to the solution was put the method as `default` inside an internal interface and change `myapi.MyAbstract` to implement `MyInternalInterface`. So that, MyClass would inherit that method and it wouldn't be able to being called from outside of the API bundle. But it doesn't prevent of being overridden at client bundle.

Is there another way of doing that?

Comment: why  wouldn't a private method in the abstract class do the trick?

Comment: Because it has to be called from another class.

Comment: have you tried "final" modifier with less restrictions?

Comment: I tried that, but an interface cannot declare a final method, even it being default. And if I'd put it in the abstract class it could be called from client classes.

Comment: Extends is for abstract classes. Do you mean implements?

Comment: Ok. You tried both. How about a little composition over inheritance? Wrap the sensitive method in a private Field. This way is restricted and can't be overridden  Let me know if this works. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: The method has to be seen from the same bundle scope. As a private field it woudn't be seen from another class. Just to remeber, I'm also talking about OSGi visibility.

Comment: With a field you prevent the overriding. Play with encapsulation or further composition achieve what you need

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I understand MyAbstract and MyClass are in different packages.  (If they would be in the same package check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for package-private access level).

The interface you define the method on will need to have at least protected visibility, otherwise your class `MyClass`, which is in another package cannot read it.

A method on an interface is by definition public and cannot be final.  Therefore a default method on an interface is visible to all classes and can be overriden.

You could do like this:

```
public abstract class MyAbstract {
    protected final void foo() {}
}

public class MyClass extends MyAbstract {
}
```

The foo method will be visible by all classes extending from `MyAbstract`, but the method cannot be overriden anymore, because it has been marked `final`

Comment: The restriction needed is between OSGi bundles and not java packages.

Comment: The foo method can't be visible from any non-api classes, even those that extends MyAbstract. It must have the private behaviour outsite the api-bundle, but public behaviour inside it. The restriction is only between OSGi bundles.

Comment: From the moment that MyClass is in another package than MyAbstract, you need to expose anything you want MyClass to see from MyAbstract with at least protected visibility.  Once it has this visibility, you cannot make it private for other packages.

Comment: Is it a possibility to make MyClass itself package-private?  It may then use a protected method from MyAbstract, but external libraries cannot access MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

If your interface has different scoped method, you should ask yourself if you do not violate the Single Responsibility principle. For example, you could create 2 API Interface (different packages or bundles) if they need both to be accessed from elsewhere.

However, if it's only for internal usage, you could create a second interface, more specific, in the implementation bundle/not exported package.

For example : MyAbstract (API) <--- MySpecificAbstract (Interface, but in IMPL) <------- MyClass (IMPL).

Comment: I agree with you, but we must not break existing code. There are classes that already extend MyAbstract (API) and if I added a new one between MyClass and MyAbstract, MyClass would have to change as well.

Comment: If you add new methods on an API exposed as a service, it won't break any bundle making reference to it. And if it's not a service but an Export-Package, you will stay runtime compatible. The only problem is when you'll want to compile again the Implementation Bundle with the new version in your Compile Dependency. 

But for example, nothing stops you to have that situation :
Compile : 1.1.0 IMPL use 1.0.0 API &
Runtime : 1.1.0 IMPL with 1.1.0 API (new methods)

That's the huge advantage of OSGI for those cases. You can add methods without prob if the IMPL keeps the same compile dep